# Question on error minimization, bias and variance

Tags: measurement-error, kernel-smoothing

I have been using Matlab to approximate a density function using histograms with a fixed number of bins. The histogram is on the interval $[-10,10]$ with a bin size of $0.05$. This makes 400 bins.

The variable is the number of samples that is being studied. I have been increasing the number of samples from 5,000 to 50 million in powers of ten, and I have noticed that the variance that resulted in the histogram plots increases with the increase in the number of samples.

I realized this is the 'bias-variance trade off' which was asked before.

Until now, I do not understand what is meant by 'bias'. And the question will be, how much is 'enough'? How many samples do I need so that density estimation is just enough?

Any ideas?

Comment: More samples generally leads to better density estimation, and a more accurate representation of variance. Do you have more details of the exact procedure you are implementing and nature of your data ? How are you measuring variance ?

Comment: I am optimizing a function using 'agents' (virtual particles). With this, I am making use of a histogram to count the number of agents located in a certain interval. I have kept the following as control variables: scale, size of windows, number of bins in the histogram,  function to be optimized. The only thing that I have changed is the number of agents used. Few agents mean a not-so-smooth distribution traced. If you increase them, you will get an idea of how distribution looks like, increasing it further somehow increases the variance.

Comment: Variance is really the deviation from the mean. I am not sure how this happened or if I mis/understood the concept of bias-variance tradeoff completely. I measured variance by keeping the scales and all factors constant, and observing at the 100th iteration. I'm not sure how this works out.

Comment: When you say samples in your question, are you referring to your particle models, and not samples of the underlying data  ?

Comment: by number of samples, i mean number of agents i put. more samples = more agents searching for an optimum.

Comment: Bias is systematic repeatable error in the model. With some machine learning algorithms, increasing the model complexity can cause an increase in variance, often with a decrease in bias. But if you aren't changing the number of underlying data samples for your models, but are simply combining identical agents that would tend to improve the accuracy of your measurements of bias and variance. If you have a combination strategy which acts to increase the overall model complexity  then you may find variance increases.

Answer (score 0):

This theorem [page 129 Theorem 6.11](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=wpk_Y3j-2_0C&printsec=frontcover&dq=all%20nonparametric%20methods&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-HwiVYQKzOJqq_CAoAU&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=page%20127&f=false) can answer your question well,

Suppose that $f'$ is absolutely continues and that $\int(f'(u))^2du<\infty$. Then,
\begin{align}
R(\hat{f}_n,f)=\frac{h^2}{12}\int(f'(u))^2du+\frac{1}{nh}+o(h^2)+o(\frac{1}{n})
\end{align}
where $h$ is the number of bins and $R(a,b)$ is a risk function of the form of $R=\mathbb{E}(L)$ that $L=\int(\hat{f}_n(x)-f(x))^2dx$.
Also the value $h^*$ that minimizes the risk is 
\begin{align}
h^*=\frac{1}{n^{1/3}}(\frac{6}{\int(f'(u))^2du})^{1/3}
\end{align}
You can consider approximately the first term as variance and the second term as bias. Note that if h increases then variance increases and bias decreases. Hope the solution is clear.

Comment: What is the definition of the function o() ?

Comment: o (small letter o) determines the speed of error. Roughly speaking, that means the error tends to zero at the speed of n and h squared.

Comment: thank you, how is $o()$ defined ?

Comment: see http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/littleOnotation.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how the risk (Loss) is function of execution time ?

Comment: O() and o() are mathematical concepts and it might take time to make yourself familiar with them. Please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem

Comment: Thank you, I'm familiar with the concepts of various $o$ notations, what I'm less clear of is how the loss function in your answer  is affected by them and how it would interact with any arbitrary algorithm?

Comment: This theorem works just for histograms. I am not sure about what you mean by 'arbitrary algorithm'. The result is asymptotic and like other asymptotic theorems, it is a function of some parameter, precisely the number of observations and bandwidth in our case.